# Computing parallel connected resistance

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, intervals

Below two algebraically equivalent formula for parallel resistors:

```
par1(r1, r2) = (r1 * r2) / (r1 + r2), or

par2(r1, r2) = 1 / (1/r1 + 1/r2)
```

Following two python functions, each of which computes the parallel_resistors formula :

```
def par1(r1, r2):
    return div_interval(mul_interval(r1, r2), add_interval(r1, r2))

def par2(r1, r2):
    one = interval(1, 1)
    rep_r1 = div_interval(one, r1)
    rep_r2 = div_interval(one, r2)
    return div_interval(one, add_interval(rep_r1, rep_r2))
```

Below is an interval arithmetic abstraction that is used by aforementioned functions `par1` and `par2`.

```
def interval(a, b):
    """Construct an interval from a to b. """
    return (a, b)

def lower_bound(x):
    """Return the lower bound of interval x. """
    return x[0]

def upper_bound(x):
    """Return the upper bound of interval x. """
    return x[1]

def div_interval(x, y):
    """Return the interval that contains the quotient of any value in x divided
    by any value in y.

    Division is implemented as the multiplication of x by the reciprocal of y.
    >>> str_interval(div_interval(interval(-1, 2), interval(4, 8)))
    '-0.25 to 0.5'
    """
    assert (lower_bound(y) > 0  or upper_bound(y) < 0), "what it means to divide by an interval that spans zero"
    reciprocal_y = interval(1/upper_bound(y), 1/lower_bound(y))
    return mul_interval(x, reciprocal_y)


def str_interval(x):
    """Return a string representation of interval x.
    >>> str_interval(interval(-1, 2))
    '-1 to 2'
    """
    return '{0} to {1}'.format(lower_bound(x), upper_bound(x))

def add_interval(x, y):
    """Return an interval that contains the sum of any value in interval x and
    any value in interval y.
    >>> str_interval(add_interval(interval(-1, 2), interval(4, 8)))
    '3 to 10'
    """
    lower = lower_bound(x) + lower_bound(y)
    upper = upper_bound(x) + upper_bound(y)
    return interval(lower, upper)

def mul_interval(x, y):
    """Return the interval that contains the product of any value in x and any
    value in y.

    >>> str_interval(mul_interval(interval(-1, 2), interval(4, 8)))
    '-8 to 16'
    """
    p1 = lower_bound(x) * lower_bound(y)
    p2 = lower_bound(x) * upper_bound(y)
    p3 = upper_bound(x) * lower_bound(y)
    p4 = upper_bound(x) * upper_bound(y)
    return interval(min(p1, p2, p3, p4), max(p1, p2, p3, p4))
```

Test outcome:

```
>>> r1 = interval(1, 2) 
>>> r2 = interval(3, 4)
>>> par1(r1, r2) 
(0.5, 2.0) 
>>> par2(r1, r2) 
(0.75, 1.3333333333333333)
```

We notice the different outcome from `par1` and `par2`, which compute by different but algebraically equivalent expressions.
For the above given input r1 and r2, below is the computation.

```
par1 --> return mul_interval((3, 8), (1/6, 1/4)) = (1/2, 2)
=======
rep_r1 = div_interval((1, 1), (1, 2)) = (1/2, 1)
rep_r2 = div_interval((1, 1), (3, 4)) =  (1/4, 1/3)
par2 --> return  div_interval((1, 1), (3/4, 4/3)) = (3/4, 4/3)
```

The reason for different interval is due to IEEE floating point format, where every `div_interval` lose precision.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: The upperbound should be `x[-1]` I guess?

Comment: @anmol_uppal Please test and find the answer for your question.

Comment: Please give reason for downvote, to further refine this question

Comment: Personally, I'm struggling with the concept of having an 'interval' to describe a resistor. Why on earth do you need two numbers to describe something that possesses a quantity, resistance, which can be expressed as a single number?

Comment: @SiHa OK. Resistance of a device is mentioned as for example `3.5 ohms with +/- 0.15 tolerance` in real world. So, we need all values between `(3.35, 3.65)` including endpoints.

Comment: @overexchange Ah. That makes more sense. This code still seems terribly complicated for such a simple operation though. I would say that the reason for your different results is probably because there is a mistake somewhere in all that code, rather than floating point representation error.

Comment: @overexchange Your input variables are all integers. Python2 does not convert the quotient of integers to a float when necessary. However, Python 3.6.5 yields exactly the same results for both functions.

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid your reasoning for why the two functions give different results is not correct. Floating point rounding can be a real issue, but for most computations (including the ones here) the error is very, very small. It's only when you're testing for exact equality or when you've combined a large number of floating point computations that the error might become significant.

The real issue here is that in `par1`, your `r1` and `r2` intervals both appear on both sides of a division operation. When your division function computes the reciprocal of its second argument, it reverses the order of the interval boundaries, so the upper bound of the input effects the lower bound of the output.

When the same interval is part of both the divisor and the dividend, you'll get a wider interval than you should. That's because the code doesn't know that a result at one extreme for one of the copies of the interval must also mean the same same extreme for the other one.

Consider the calculation of `r / r`, for the interval `r = (a, b)`. Your `div_interval` function will compute the result to be `(a/b, b/a)`, when by basic algebra, we know the result should be `(1, 1)` (since any number divided by itself is 1). The division code however, has to assume that each of its arguments is independent of the other. If the divisor turns out to be at its interval's maximum bound (`b`), it might be dividing a dividend at its minimum bound (`a`). It can't know that those two things can't happen at the same time.

The second formula avoids this issue by having each input interval only appear in one place. You can actually allow a little bit of duplication. As long as there's no subtraction, division or multiplication by intervals containing negative bounds, there should be no problems.

Comment: If I make it as `reciprocal_y = interval(1/lower_bound(y), 1/upper_bound(y))` It does not make any difference. because we are picking the `min` and `max` in `mul_interval`

Comment: That's true, the multiplication code does take the min and max value of the products of the boundaries, but if the bounds are all positive, the minimum will be the product of the lower bounds of the inputs, and the maximum will be the product of the upper bounds of the inputs. Not reversing the values when you compute the reciprocal will give you a bogus interval (the lower bound will be larger than the upper bound).

Comment: How do we change `par1` and `par2` to get similar results?

Comment: @overexchange: `par2` *is* a fixed version of `par1` already. You don't need to make them give the same answer, just understand why `par1` gets it wrong. Reading the assignment text from the first draft of your question, Eva is mostly right. The multiple references are the problem in `par1`, but not all formulas with multiple references will cause trouble.

Comment: I could not  agree with this point: `when by basic algebra, we know the result should be (1, 1)` . if `r = (1, 2)`  algebarically division formulae as mentioned in [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic) cannot be `(1, 1)`.

Comment: By "basic" I was referring to non-interval arithmetic. That's appropriate, since the interval is just a way of specifying some uncertainty about a single real number. `r/r` is going to be `1`, regardless of the error we had measuring it. The problem you're supposed to be learning about is that interval arithmetic doesn't handle this situation well. Avoiding having the same interval in more than one place in a formula is a way of working around the limitation.

Comment: Here is one explanation for `par1` and `par2` giving different results in [Q5](http://cs61a.org/hw-sol/hw04/#q5) with an example `(-1, 1)* (-1, 1) ---> (-1, 1)`. In this explanation, the keyword is "Multiple reference problem"

Comment: *"When the same interval is part of both the divisor and the dividend, you'll get a wider interval than you should."* sums it up precisely.  A mathematical phenomenon based on interval arithmetic, rather than a programming error. Certainly not floating point.  OP could, of course, convince themself floating point was nothing to do with it by using e.g. intervals `(8,16)` or `(2,4)` where there reciprocals of each bound can be represented exactly under IEEE floating point specification with no rounding error whatsoever... Nice answer and explanatory comments

Answer (score 1):

## Multiple parallel impedances — foolproof

The total impedance of a number of [impedances in parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_%28operator%29) corresponds to the [harmonic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean) of these impedances divided by the number of parallel impedances.

```
from scipy import stats

def par(array):
    """Calculate the impedance of an array of parallel impedances"""
    return stats.hmean(array)/len(array)

In [1]: par([2.7, 3.3, 10])
Out[1]: 1.29299
```

Answer (score -1):

To prove the point that it's not rounding errors, here is some code that uses both methods to calculate the parallel resistance. It's not intended to be neat, or particularly efficient, just to show that the two ways of calculating yield exactly the same result.

```
def par1(r1,r2):
    r1lower = float(r1[0])
    r1upper = float(r1[1])
    r2lower = float(r2[0])
    r2upper = float(r2[1])
    low = 1/((1/r1lower)+(1/r2lower))
    high = 1/((1/r1upper)+(1/r2upper))
    return(low, high)

def par2(r1,r2):
    r1lower = float(r1[0])
    r1upper = float(r1[1])
    r2lower = float(r2[0])
    r2upper = float(r2[1])
    low = (r1lower * r2lower) / (r1lower + r2lower)
    high = (r1upper * r2upper) / (r1upper + r2upper)
    return(low, high)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print par1((1,2),(3,4))
    print par2((1,2),(3,4))
```

Output:

```
(0.75, 1.3333333333333333)
(0.75, 1.3333333333333333)
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

Somewhere in your code you have a mistake...

Comment: par1/par2 comes from [here](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61a/fa12/hw/hw3.html)

Comment: Your code gets the right result for `par2` (using the `par1` formula from the question) because it assumes (correctly, as it turns out) that the lower bound for the output comes from combining the lower bounds of the two input intervals (and the same for the upper bounds). That's not always true of interval operations though. The upper bound of `a/b` is effected by the lower bound of `b`, for instance. This is the source of the logical error in the code. No general purpose interval code will get `a/a` correct.

Comment: @Blckknght: I understand now. I suppose it should have been obvious that no-one would write such obscure code other than as an academic excercise.

Comment: @Blckknght From this [code](https://github.com/shamhub/CS61A_Fall2012/blob/master/obs.txt) I understand that, The upper bound of `a/b` is effected by the lower bound of `b`. But I would like to understand, how this point is related to different outputs of `par1` and `par2`?